# phpstan complains about Doctrine Migrations in Symfony 3.4 with Flex project

Tags: symfony, doctrine-migrations, symfony-flex, phpstan

I have a project built on Symfony 3.4 with Flex and I've added phpstan to it for static analysis.

It is complaining about not finding my migration classes:

`Class DoctrineMigrations\Version20180831185050 was not found while trying to analyse it - autoloading is probably not configured properly.`

Indeed, the files generated by Doctrine Migrations don't fit with the autoloader pattern, but works just fine otherwise.

Is there anything I can do to stop complaining about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [exclude files from analysis](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan#exclude-files-from-analysis)

Create `phpstan.neon` configuration file in the project directory and insert:

```
parameters:
    excludes_analyse:
        - %currentWorkingDirectory%/src/DoctrineMigrations/*
```

Every file inside `src/DoctrineMigrations` directory will be excluded from analysis.

Comment: That worked, but with Flex the directory is src/Migrations, without Doctrine in the name.

Comment: It's better to include with `autoload_directories` than to exclude, like in @ondřej-mirtes answer

Answer (score 9):

You can add the directory with the migrations to Composer autoloader, or **preferably** add it to `autoload_directories` in `phpstan.neon`:

```
parameters:
    autoload_directories:
        - src/Migrations
```

Check out the [Autoloading](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/autoloading) section in the PHPStan’s documentation for more details.

Comment: Hm, not sure about this. If you look at `config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml` the symfony devs made a comment `"# namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded"`.

Comment: @agoldev While in application context yes, they should not be autoloaded to prevent them from executing by accident, in case of PhpStan you want to run checks on them to see if they are syntactically correct. Therefore you add them to PhpStan **only**